# Find shelvesets via Visual Studio as quickly as possible

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

I need to review many shelvesets using Visual Studio every day.  I have added the `TfsPendingChanges` command to the my toolbar, but the rest of the procedure to access a shelveset (Actions/Find Shelvesets) still feels clumsy.  In fact, shelveset review has nothing to do with my own pending changes. And VS11 just made it even one step longer than it already was.

Is there any way to add "Find Shelvesets" in some form directly to a menu or to a toolbar, in Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you go to right click and then "Customize" on any toolbar, it will bring up a dialog.  Press the "Keyboard" button on it, choose File.TfsUnShelvePendingChanges and assign a Hot Key to it. I do believe that the Source Control Explorer window needs to be open and active for your hot key to work.

OR...This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but if you have the Source Control Explorer window open and active, then <kbd>ALT-F</kbd> <kbd>ALT-R</kbd> <kbd>ALT-F</kbd> <kbd>ALT-F</kbd> <kbd>ALT-S</kbd> will bring up the dialog. That is actually navigating File/Source Control/Find/Find Shelvesets.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to work with Shelvesets is to use the new My Work feature. By suspending and resuming work Visual Studio will automatically do all the Shelveset magic for you with a simple drag/drop of the task that you want to have in progress.

The same applies to reviews, Suspend your current work, or create a new temporary workspace, open the Review Request, let it unshelve the changes automatically and when you're done go back to where you were by resuming your previous tasks.

It's really great once you get the hang of it. That it uses Shelvesets under the hood is nice to know, but this way you don't really need to know, it just works.

As for TWA Diff, [there've been great improvements with TFS 2012 Update 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/01/30/announcing-visual-studio-2012-update-2-vs2012-2.aspx) which is almost ready to be released...

Comment: +1 because this way I can also use VS/Resharper/CodeRush code navigation capabilities while reviewing something large.  On the other hand, this answer only solves the problem after the whole organization is on the new ALM.

Comment: Correct, and has Visual Studio Premium or Higher. But if you have it, use it :).

Answer (score 1):

If this is only for reviews then maybe Team Web Access would be better for you?
Just navigate to http://:8080/tfs/web/, select team project, then click Source Tab and Find Shelvesets. You can then open each shelveset in new browser window and it will list all changes and allows you to quickly do compare etc.

Comment: It's not just reviews.  A worse problem is that I probably cannot tell TWA which diff tool to use to show the diffs.  (We already have TWA links generated into code review e-mails, per file changed, but most people find it useful just for simple changes).

Answer (score 0):

Command that you are looking for is **TfsUnshelvePendingChanges** under **File**.

Right click on any toolbar, click on customize and a dialog will open. Go to 'Commands' tab on the top.

Choose appropriate button out of Menu Bar | Toolbar | Context Menu. Select the desired option under that. My favorite is to add it to Toolbar>Work Item Tracing (toolbar where New Item/Open Item appears).

[image: Customize dialog]

After choosing from above step appropriately, click on 'New Command'. Then select to File>TfsUnShelvePendingChanges. This will add a shortcut to unshelve changes.

[image: Choose command]

Thanks to @Alex for pointing out the correct command name. Writing here separately for people looking for answers in future.