# TFS Web Access and large files

Tags: tfs

When viewing a whole shelveset diff in TFS Web Access, the largest source files are accompanied with a yellow bar that says "*Displayed content is truncated due to maximum viewable content limit.*"

When I click on that single large file to see just its diff, I get another yellow bar.  This time it says "*The file contents were truncated since they exceeded the maximum file content length. Browse to the individual files to download full content.*"

Okay, maybe this tool just won't show large files to me.

- How do I "browse to the individual files" as the yellow bar suggests?  Will that give me both versions that I need to diff (shelved and unmodified)?
- Is the size limit configurable anywhere?
- Is there any way to use TFS Web Access with a
  user configurable diff tool?  (I would have many other good uses for that.)

The only workaround I am aware of is to open Visual Studio, [painfully look up the shelveset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13841302/1235565), and view it using my configured diff tool which doesn't care whether the source files are obese or not.

I'm using TFS version 12.0.30324.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select just a single file you should get a download button. Clicking this will retrieve just that single file in it's entirety.

[image]

On non-shelvesets it's next to the edit button, but I dought that edit is available on shelvesets.

Comment: Edit is not available on somebody else's shelvesets.  Not even on my own shelvesets.  It appears that this works in "Explorer" but not in "Shelvesets".  It at least explains the message I'm getting a little.

Answer (score 0):

After asking, I discovered some other ways to search and found out that [this limitation is specific to TFS 2012 and unpatched TFS 2013](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/05ddf65a-bc03-42ea-873e-af2aa886b162/tfs-displayed-content-is-truncated-due-to-maximum-viewable-content-limit?forum=tfsgeneral).  Maybe this helps someone.

(This does not solve my own problem as I cannot quickly achieve TFS server upgrade so I'm still interested in a better answer.  I'd like to extend my knowledge of TFS Web Access and I found the online resources lacking.)